# javaFX jar application

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with javaFX jar application.
When I compile my project in IDEA it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1263.png)

But when I build jar application, after pressing `AUTHORIZATION` in first window,
it doesn't open next window. I use FXML scenes.
First window is calling from `start()` method in `Main` class, others from controllers classes.

Method in main class.

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Interface.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Client");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And one of the controllers class:

```
 @FXML
public void Autentification(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {


    UserInform.AccauntName = name;
    UserInform.UserName = name;


    int intPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
    messages.PrintMessage("Authentication started\n", Out);

    ConnectionForUI.session.tryConnect(name, pass, host, intPort);

  //Run next window
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../ClientField.fxml"));
                        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        stage.setTitle("Client");
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                        stage.show();

}
```

`Autentification` method runs when I press Authorization button, and here runs next window.
I'm new in Java FX so if you know how to repaid this problem, I will be very grateful.

Exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOzBr.png)

Comment: Try running the Jar from the command line to see if it prints out any error messages.

Comment: yes, it wrote IllegalStateException. Location is not set, but I don't know how to reslove this

Comment: Don't use `..` in `getResource`. Try the absolute path to the resource.

Comment: your jar can't find the resource. @Slaw was faster than me thou. Idea sets a relative path that you don't have when you export the jar. Try with absolute path/relative path from your actual .jar path

Comment: But it doesnt see way to FXML

Comment: You say I have to paste my controller class to FXML files folder?

Comment: no, please don't do that. you need to know the absolute path of your FXML file (or the relative from the actual path of your jar), and put it in the getResource(...) method

Comment: Thank you so match, it works, I am in debt to you.
Дуже вам дякую (UA)

Comment: glad you fixed it, high five bro!!

Comment: Please Put the Exception as Text inside here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the way to me FXML  files. You have to set absolute way to files, like`"/file_name.fxml".` It helped to me.